# Set X,Y margins depending on current location of the WPF control

Tags: wpf, canvas, user-controls

I made a simple user control that renders a simple music bar.

```
<UserControl x:Class="EzHarmony.ScoreUserControl.BarRenderer"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EzHarmony.ScoreUserControl"
         mc:Ignorable="d" >
<Canvas>
    <StackPanel Name="StackPanel_Staff" Orientation="Vertical" Canvas.ZIndex="1">
        <Line Stroke="Black" X1="0" Y1="10" X2="200" Y2="10"></Line>
        <Line Stroke="Black" X1="0" Y1="10" X2="200" Y2="10"></Line>
        <Line Stroke="Black" X1="0" Y1="10" X2="200" Y2="10"></Line>
        <Line Stroke="Black" X1="0" Y1="10" X2="200" Y2="10"></Line>
        <Line Stroke="Black" X1="0" Y1="10" X2="200" Y2="10"></Line>
    </StackPanel>

    <Line Stroke="Black" X1="0" Y1="10" X2="0" Y2="52"></Line>
    <Line Stroke="Black" X1="200" Y1="10" X2="200" Y2="52"></Line>
</Canvas>
```

and here is a sample user control that renders 4-bar music score

```
<UserControl x:Class="EzHarmony.ScoreUserControl.OneStaffScore"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EzHarmony.ScoreUserControl"
         mc:Ignorable="d" >
<WrapPanel>
    <local:BarRenderer></local:BarRenderer>
    <local:BarRenderer></local:BarRenderer>
    <local:BarRenderer></local:BarRenderer>
    <local:BarRenderer></local:BarRenderer>
</WrapPanel>
```

but the result shows only one bar.
[image]

I guess it is because of **Line**'s **X, Y** margins are all same.
how can I fix it so every Bar renderer's lines will be drawn in their area?

The expected output should be something like:
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: add a picture of expected output, please

Comment: @ASh I added a picture!

Comment: @ASh I tried to put BarRenderes in WrapPanel/StackPanel with an option   Orientation="Horizontal", but it doesn't work. I use OneStaffScore just like this:
<MainWindow ...>
<Grid>
<uc:OneStaffScore/>
</Grid>
</MainWindow>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

somehow all BarRenderers (Canvases) shrunk to zero. add them some size:

```
<WrapPanel>
    <local:BarRenderer Width="200" Height="52"/>
    <local:BarRenderer Width="200" Height="52"/>
    <local:BarRenderer Width="200" Height="52"/>
    <local:BarRenderer Width="200" Height="52"/>
</WrapPanel>
```

it looked like only one bar, because Canvas content is displayed even outside bounds and 4 BarRenderers were displayed on top on each other, in the same location

Comment: Спасибо большое! вы выручили тупого любителя програмированния:)

Comment: @JoyHyukLee, I do have some experience in WPF, but was really confused anyway (admittedly I didn't use Canvas much).  good luck in coding!